# Calling a method of a child class from an array list of objects of the parent class

Tags: java

I've searched for a solution to this but I still don't understand what to do here. This program is supposed to mimic an atm machine that subtracts from the balance with checks and adds money with deposits.

I have this parent class:

```
public class Transaction
{

private int transNumber;
private int transId;
private double transAmt;

public Transaction(int number, int id, double amount)
{
    transNumber = number;
    transId = id;
    transAmt = amount;
}

public int getTransNumber()
{
    return transNumber;
}

public int getTransId()
{
    return transId;
}

public double getTransAmount()
{
    return transAmt;
}
}
```

I have an array list (transList) that stores objects of Transaction for every withdrawl/deposit.

The child class is:

```
public class Check extends Transaction
{
private int checkNumber; // check number for each check transaction

public Check(int tId, double tAmt, int tCount, int checkNumber) {
    super(tCount, tId, tAmt);
    this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
}

public int getCheckNumber() {
    return checkNumber;
}

public void setCheckNumber(int checkNumber) {
    this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
}
}
```

What I need to do is print out in JOptionPane the check numbers if the user asks for them.

In main I have:

```
checkNumStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter check number:");
                checkNum = Integer.parseInt(checkNumStr);
                checkAmtStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Eneter check amount:");
                checkAmt = Double.parseDouble(checkAmtStr);

                Check c = new Check(1, checkAmt, acctCheck.gettransCount(), checkNum);

                acctCheck.addTrans(c);
```

I'm not sure if I've been clear enough. I haven't asked a question on here before. What I need to know is how to call Check.getCheckNumber() from an array list of objects of the parent class Transaction.

EDIT: transList is located in another class: Checking Account:

```
public class CheckingAccount extends Account
{
  private double totalServiceCharge;
  private static ArrayList<Transaction> transList;
  // keeps a list of Transaction objects for the account
  private int transCount = 0;   
  // the count of Transaction objects and used as the ID for each transaction
  NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();



  public CheckingAccount()
  {
      transList = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
      totalServiceCharge = 0;
  }

  public double getServiceCharge()
  {
        return totalServiceCharge;
  }

    public void setServiceCharge(double currentServiceCharge)
  {
        totalServiceCharge += currentServiceCharge;
  }

    // adds a transaction object to the transList
    public void addTrans(Transaction newTrans)
    {
        transList.add (newTrans);
        transCount++;
    }

    //returns the current value of transCount;
    public int gettransCount()
    {
        return transCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is -- don't do this. Your Transaction class should *not* have this ArrayList as it belongs elsewhere, not in the parent class.

Answer (score 2):

When you're building classes, you should think of the `has-a`  `is-a` relationship.

An example in your case,

You have a `Transaction` class.  You have a `Check` class that `extends Transaction`.  When you `extend`, you're saying that a `Check` `is-a` `Transaction`, which is not true.  But does `Transaction` `has-a` (or have a) `Check`? Yes!  So in that case, You would separate `Check` from being an extension of `Transaction` and do something like this:

```
public class Transaction {
    Check check;  // This is an example of a has-a relationship
} 

public class Check {  // notice how Check doesn't extend Transaction
                      // anymore.  As it shouldn't, because they don't
}                     // share any common properties
```

If you want an `ArrayList` of `Check`s, I would put it in the `Account` class because an `Account` does `has-a`(have a) `checkHistory`

```
public class Account {
    ArrayList<Check> checkHistory = new ArrayList<Check>();

    public ArrayList<Check> getCheckHistory() {
        return checkHistorty;
    }
}
```

So you can call the `checkHistory` from the `Account` class, which makes perfect sense

```
Account myAccount = new Account();

ArrayList<Check> list = myAccount.getCheckHistory();

for (Check check : list) {
    System.out.print(check.someCheckProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Check` is a special kind of `Transaction`, you can't call `getCheckNumber()` on a list of `Transaction`s, since that's not where the `getCheckNumber()` method is declared.

What you *can* do if you have a heterogeneous list of `Transaction`s (some of which are `Check`s, some of which are some other kind of `Transaction`) is something like the following for each list item:

```
int checkNum = -1;
if (trans instanceof Check) {
    checkNum = ((Check) trans).getCheckNumber();
}
....
```

Of course, in this case you have to be prepared to deal with the `-1` (or whatever you make your default check number) for the items that don't end up being `Check`s.

**Edit:**

To address @Hovercraft's perfectly reasonable comment...I'd say what you probably want to do is, instead of giving `Check` a `getCheckNumber()` method, override `getTransId()` (or provide another method for identifying `Transaction`s in a generic sort of way) and return the check number from there, following the same pattern with other `Transaction` subclasses, if there are any. That way, a loop over `Transaction` objects doesn't need a bunch of nasty casts.

Comment: I agree; I didn't say it was good design...of course, that begs the question as to why I posted it, doesn't it? There are use cases for this sort of thing, of course; while this might not be one, I guess I didn't feel like writing a new interface, etc.